# Would you ever use the value assigned in a if let statement

Tags: swift

In the following code, would you ever use the value assigned to `tempName`? In other words, is there any other use for `tempName` other than for the `Optional Binding`.

```
var name:String?

name = "Nathan"

if let tempName = name{
    print("It's not nil, it has a value")
    print(tempName) // Nathan - Would you ever use this value
    print(name!) // Nathan
}else{
    print("It's nil, no value has been set")
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you only want to check whether the value is `nil`, then optional binding doesn't make sense because you don't need to *bind*. You can use plain old `name != nil` or `if let _ = name {`. Using `!` for the variable you have just bound seems like an error because the optional binding is supposed to avoid `!`.

Comment: The whole point of *optional binding* is to safely create an unwrapped variable that you can then use freely without worrying out unwrapping again!  As @Sulthan said, if you're just checking if it's `nil`, then check for `nil` or assign it to `_`. So yes, absolutely, there is a use for the variable after the *optional binding*.

Comment: I guess my problem was in not understanding what `Optional Binding` was, I thought that the main use for `if let` it was to check for `nil` which is definitely not the case, my bad. Thank you  @Sulthan and @ vacawama -  for pointing that out, make sense now.

Comment: This is huge swift anti pattern. There's nothing stopping you from doing `name = nil` prior to `print(name!)`, which will cause a crash. It's always preferable to use the safely unwrapped, immutable value bound by `if let`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example No , but imagine a situation where you want to do 10 tasks with the `name` and pass it to multiple functions, in those cases yes.If you don't use it you have to write an if check for every single of those tasks  and functions (because an optional causes other methods return value to be optional as well) which makes your code less readable and complicated without any reason.

Imaging 10

```
if name?.somefunction() != nil { 
      // do something if it is available 
}else{
      // it's not available. Do something appropriate
}
```

Comment: My problem was in not understanding what `Optional Binding` was. Makes totally sense now, Thanks a lot.